# Cloud formation error: Invalid template resource property 'Path'"

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml

I have an issue with the YAML template that is creating a Kafka cluster. I think it is an indentation error at line 457 or below. At the moment I have the following error:

> Invalid template resource property 'Path'

The code is [here](https://github.com/bigpafik/Kafka_Connect-_Cloudformation-_yaml-/blob/master/07_17_19_kafka.yaml). Could someone explain what the error actually means?

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-instanceprofile.html) path should be inside 'Properties' block. You have it 1 level above inside 'InstanceIAMRole' block.